# Pie-chart in python

Tags: python, matplotlib, pie-chart

I am trying to make a pie chart with python but all the labels are overlapping. Is there any way to try to ensure that they are inside the pie chart but not overlapping?

Here's my code

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

labels = ['Cropland', 'Forest', 'Cloud', 'Shadow', 'Water', 'Grassland', 'Bare ground']
sizes = [1737019, 105209472, 5210012, 4638330, 148082,1276550, 2340935]
colors = ['tab:blue', 'tab:orange', 'tab:green', 'tab:red', 'tab:purple', 'tab:brown', 'tab:pink']
patches, texts = plt.pie(sizes, colors=colors, shadow=False, startangle=90)
plt.pie(sizes, labels=labels, autopct='%1.0f%%', pctdistance=1.4, labeldistance=1.8)
plt.legend(patches, labels, loc="lower left")
plt.axis('equal')
plt.tight_layout()
plt.savefig('LULC_20200425.png', bbox_inches='tight', dpi=600)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reduce and rotate the labels.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.figure(dpi=150)
labels = ['Cropland', 'Forest', 'Cloud', 'Shadow', 'Water', 'Grassland', 'Bare ground']
sizes = [1737019, 105209472, 5210012, 4638330, 148082,1276550, 2340935]

colors = ['tab:blue', 'tab:orange', 'tab:green', 'tab:red', 'tab:purple', 'tab:brown', 'tab:pink']

patches, texts = plt.pie(sizes, colors=colors, shadow=False, startangle=90,textprops={'fontsize': 8})
plt.pie(sizes, labels=labels, autopct='%1.0f%%', pctdistance=1.15, labeldistance=0.50,rotatelabels = True, textprops = dict(rotation_mode = 'anchor', va='center', ha='left', fontsize=8))

plt.legend(patches, labels, loc="lower left")
plt.axis('equal')
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can rotate the labels to reduce the overlap and also use a larger figure

```
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(6,6))

labels = ['Cropland', 'Forest', 'Cloud', 'Shadow', 'Water', 'Grassland', 'Bare ground']
sizes = [1737019, 105209472, 5210012, 4638330, 148082,1276550, 2340935]
colors = ['tab:blue', 'tab:orange', 'tab:green', 'tab:red', 'tab:purple', 'tab:brown', 'tab:pink']
patches, texts = plt.pie(sizes, colors=colors, shadow=False, startangle=90)
plt.pie(sizes, labels=labels, autopct='%1.0f%%', pctdistance=1.1, labeldistance=0.65, rotatelabels =True,
       textprops = dict(rotation_mode = 'anchor', va='center', ha='left'),)
plt.legend(patches, labels, loc="lower left")
plt.axis('equal')
plt.tight_layout()
```

[image]